# How to use another domain for a specific url?

Tags: wordpress, dns

I'm building a WordPress website for a client and can't figure out what to do here. I'm using translatepress to make my website multilingual and the client wants to have another domain for different language. So the default domain is example.com but English version is example.com/en . Is it possible to add another domain which replaces example.com/en and is still functional by pressing all the links? So it's like example2.com points to example.com/en , but not as a url forwarding, but it replaces the whole example.com/en part completely. What are my options here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different sites in a network on different domains.  It is just on the other domain, not on both. Since WP stores internal links as absolute URLS, you need to create the sites on the correct domain from the start, or use wp-cli or similar to re-write existing links when you change.

I was about to recommend the plugin I have used, but see from https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/ that from 4.5 it's a WP native feature!

Note: i don't use translatepress but have different languages as different sites in a network.  Since you talk about sub-domains I'm assuming you do something similar

Comment: I'm not sure if get this right.  It is one website, but with a different slug. TranslatePress is not creating a duplicate, it only translates the strings and stores them in database, so when a slug for example /en is called, it reads from db. So , my main website is https://somerandomname.com and english version for it is https://somerandomname.com/en , just a slug, but with different DB data. And i want to make anotherrandomname.com , to work as the https://somerandomname.com/en . I hope i speak clearly enough. I'm just having too much information now about DNS :D

Comment: Ah!  OK, then no, my proposal won't work.  You'd need to see if you could do something in the web server layer.  Make the other domain into a proxy maybe?